# Why do labels move when scrolling? Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, scrollbar, jlabel

How do I make other jlabels stay in place when I scroll the main jlabel with the image? If I scroll down the labels don't stay, they move with the scroll. How do I solve this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
JPanel pan = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();

public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    pan.setLayout(null);

    setSize(1050,700);
    setTitle("Scroll Image");
    setResizable(false);

    JLabel background = new JLabel();
    background.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Main.png")));

    JLabel lab1 = new JLabel();
    lab1.setBounds(new Rectangle(153, 350, 140, 200));
    lab1.setText("Text1");

    JLabel lab2 = new JLabel();
    lab2.setBounds(new Rectangle(553, 350, 140, 200));
    lab2.setText("Text2");

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(background);
    scroll.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1050, 690));

    pan.add(lab1);
    pan.add(lab2);
    add(scroll);
}
```

Comment: Oh, so many better ways

Answer (score 1):

## Use a "glass pane"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test extends javax.swing.JFrame {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Test frame = new Test();
        frame.setSize(250, 250);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public Test() {
    setTitle("Scroll Image");
    
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(500, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2d.drawLine(0, 0, 500, 500);
    g2d.drawLine(500, 0, 0, 500);
    g2d.dispose();

    JLabel background = new JLabel();
    background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

    JLabel lab1 = new JLabel();
    lab1.setBounds(new Rectangle(153, 350, 140, 200));
    lab1.setText("Text1");

    JLabel lab2 = new JLabel();
    lab2.setBounds(new Rectangle(553, 350, 140, 200));
    lab2.setText("Text2");

    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(background);
    
    JPanel glassPane = new JPanel(null);
    glassPane.setOpaque(false);
    glassPane.add(lab1);
    glassPane.add(lab2);
    
    setGlassPane(glassPane);
    glassPane.setVisible(true);
    
    add(scroll);

  }
}
```